# The slideshow content on the page jumps up when the download bar appears at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever the download bar appears at the bottom, the slideshow content on the Homepage jumps up. It goes back to normal position once I close the download bar.[https://photos.app.goo.gl/F482eMfkXyfEZkdA9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFlWg.jpg).

I guess its something to do with CSS. Hope someone can help. Sorry if something similar has been asked before but I looked and could not find anything and I'm fairly new into this field.

Here is the CSS code:

```
#slideshow > div {
    width: 970px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 180px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of aligning the element to the `bottom: -5px;` use the `top` alignment to avoid this behaviour.

```
 #slideshow > div 
    {
    width: 970px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; /*  <-  change this   */ 
    right: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 180px;
    }
```

Comment: Using a `px` value you would have to guess the height of your user's screen - better to use a [vh value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) in conjunction with [css calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: Thanks so much @rafaelcastrocouto for the suggestion, changing the element to top  worked like a charm.

Comment: I have no idea how to change it to vh value, would it really matter with various screen size?